# (Excel VBA): Accessing JSON file - operation timed out

Tags: html, json, excel, vba, timeout

I'm attempting to pull data from a JSON file on the web. I'm using a dummy JSON file for the time being to get things working. My code is below, but it times out every time and doesn't return anything. The same happens if I use different URLs also.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.Send
    strResult = objHTTP.ResponseText
    MsgBox strResult
End Sub
```

In case it's relevant, I have the following libraries enabled in the file:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1

What am I missing?

EDIT: Fixed. I wasn't aware of the distinction between WinHttpRequest and XMLHTTPRequest. When using the latter, the code worked fine. Thanks all.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a special reason why using [WinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of [XMLHTTPRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(v=vs.85))?

While using `WinHttpRequest` the operating system defaults for `HTTP` requests - proxy settings for example - are **not** used and must be set explicitly:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    objHTTP.SetProxy 2, "proxyIP:proxyPort"
    URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setCredentials "username", "password", 1
    objHTTP.Send
    strResult = objHTTP.ResponseText
    MsgBox strResult
End Sub
```

The `2` in [IWinHttpRequest::SetProxy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384059(v=vs.85).aspx) is `HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY`.
The `1` in [IWinHttpRequest::SetCredentials method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384058(v=vs.85).aspx) is `HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_PROXY`.

While using `XMLHTTPRequest` the operating system defaults for `HTTP` requests are used as set in `Internet Options` in control panel. So the following should run if you are able accessing the URL via browser:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.Send
    strResult = objHTTP.ResponseText
    MsgBox strResult
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works OK here, but perhaps you should `.WaitForResponse` if things are timing out:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.Send

    objHTTP.waitforresponse

    strResult = objHTTP.ResponseText
    MsgBox strResult
End Sub
```